# create button for lines in records and update field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

i Have a table with orders,
i want to create a button per each line in the table that when clicked, will change the value of a field in that record (order status to cancelled) without redirect to any update page.
i created a link using HtmlAction but its not activating the function(see screen shot)[image]
Here is the actionLink:

```
   <td>
       <div class="text-center">
           <p>@Html.ActionLink("cancel", "CancelOrder", "Order",new { id = @order.Id })</p>
       </div>
</td>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Kobi, any updates about this case?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, i will try to apply that solution when i come back to this,
and will keep you posted, Thanks alot :)

Comment: I hope my answer can be helpful to you, waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You get a 405 error because the "CancelOrder" method should be a get request instead of a post request.
Below is a work demo:

Index View:

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsCancle)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var order in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => order.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => order.IsCancle)
            </td>    
            <td>
                <p>@Html.ActionLink("cancel", "CancelOrder", "Orders", new { id = @order.Id })</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Orders.ToListAsync());
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CancelOrder(int id)
    {
        var order = _context.Orders.Find(id);
        order.IsCancle = true;
        _context.Update(order);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Result:
[image]

By the way,if you don't want to refresh the entire page, I recommend you to use Ajax. Here is an example of using Ajax for partial refresh:

Index View:

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>   
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var order in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => order.Name)
            </td>     
            <td>           
               <button id="Cancle">Cancle</button>
               <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@order.Id" />     
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
@section Scripts
{ 
<script>
    $('#Cancle').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = $('input[name=Id ]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Orders/CancelOrder',
        type: 'post',
        data: { "id": id } ,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
});
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Orders.ToListAsync());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CancelOrder(int id)
    {
        var order = _context.Orders.Find(id);
        order.IsCancle = true;
        _context.Update(order);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Json(id);
    }
```

Result:
[image]